# How to serialize NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults to text for support e-mail?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm using Monotouch for iPhone/iPad development and I have a built in system where the user can submit a bug report from the app.  It would be nice to capture their "settings" which I store in NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults so I can see their exact configuration.

Anyone know how to capture the NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults and write out to text or file to include in the e-mail?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just attaching the .plist file directly to the e-mail and that worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You could save the `NSUserDefaults` as a plist.  Might be easier to de-code on the other end.

```
NSDictionary *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation];
[defaults writeToFile:@"path" atomically:YES];
```

---

[EDIT]

I have *no* idea if this will work.

```
var = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.DictionaryRepresentation();
```

Or just cycle through your properties and print them to a file?

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("thisorthatKey");
```

Comment: Anyone that can convert this to Monotouch C#?

Comment: suggestion is up on monotouch, sorry I can't be more help.